# how to show table data in tree structure view in asp.net c#

Tags: nested, treeview, nested-lists, hierarchical-data, nested-datalist

I have the following DataTable:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 |
| A1 | B2 | C2 |
| A2 | B2 | C2 |
| A3 | B3 | C3 |

I Want to show it in hierarchy structure like below.

```
 A1
   |_B1
      |_C1
   |_B2
      |_C2
 A2
   |_B2
      |_C2
 A3
   |_B3
      |_C3
```

I did a deep search and I could not  found something helpful.I am using asp.net c#.

Want to show it in hierarchy tree structure like.

I am using asp.net c#.